# Testing a REST API client

Tags: rest

There many tools for testing REST APIs by mimicking a client, but I need the other side- test my client.
I wrote a simple server using Flask, but I was hoping for something that includes builtin logging, scripting and configuration out of the box with no need for coding.

Comment: http://www.mock-server.com/ will enable checking how your client reacts to different service responses, including illegal and expected error responses. But it required Java coding.

Comment: You can use Properties files for MockServer to implement it as well. I often use MockServer to do a MITM attack on the SUT using it's proxy capabilities and then verify the data being sent and returned. If you submitted this as an answer I would definitely upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

[Interfake](https://github.com/basicallydan/interfake) is another option. You can create HTTP servers from a JSON file or through a straightforward JS API.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Frisbyjs](http://frisbyjs.com/). It is built on top of node.js and Jasmin suitable for end2ent testing.
I would say easy to config and use.

Comment: Frisbyjs seems to be what I am not looking for, it's a tool for testing a server's API. I want to test a client that sends requests, not receive them.

Comment: There are a number of tools you can use - searching for "mock api" gives a number of options. 

There's also http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ which is a freely available REST service you can use to test your client.